# Clicking on an "ion-toggle" using appium

Tags: ionic-framework, appium, appium-android

I am unable to activate an `<ion-toggle>` button using appium/python client.

Here is the HTML template:

```
<ion-toggle id="testaut_useauth_toggle" 
            ng-change="toggleAuth()" 
            ng-model="wizard.useauth" 
            toggle-class="toggle-calm">{{'kWizUseAuth' |
          translate}}
</ion-toggle>
```

My appium test.py code:

```
self.click_item("testaut_useauth_toggle")
def click_item(self,id, wait=5):
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_id(id)
        element.click()
        sleep(wait)
```

The error I get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: unknown error: Element <div class="item item-toggle toggle-small ng-not-empty ng-valid" id="testaut_useauth_toggle" ng-change="toggleAuth()" ng-model="wizard.useauth" toggle-class="toggle-calm" style="">...</div> is not clickable at point (180, 190). Other element would receive the click: <section ng-show="selected" ng-class="{current: selected, done: completed}" class="step current" ng-transclude="" wz-title="2" style="">...</section>
  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.91)
```

The "other element" , "wz-title" is basically an angular wizard template I am using. It is used by my app in other screens too, and I have no problem clicking on buttons, so the issue is with this toggle switch (which ionic implements as a checkbox)

Alternate approach that I tried and failed:

```
def tap_item(self,id,wait=5):
        print ('Tapping item: {}'.format(id))
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_id(id)
        #self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0]).click();", element);
        self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById(arguments[0]).click();", id);
```

There is no error here, but it doesn't activate

Any help would be appreciated.

Given this is a web app, I can't really get any location. Tap doesn't work because the method is not implemented for a WebView

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution after looking into how the `<ion-toggle>` button has been implemented and with some experimentation on which item should be the target of the click

Final solution:

```
def tap_toggle(id,wait=Wait.TOGGLE):
    element = driver.find_element_by_id(id)
    element = element.find_element_by_tag_name('label')
    element.click()
    sleep(wait)
```

Also cross posted at https://github.com/appium/python-client/issues/340